# Custom MvxTouchViewPresenter not showing subsequent ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I've written a custom `MvxTouchViewPresenter` that allows me to show either a [SlidingPanel](https://github.com/patbonecrusher/SlidingPanels.Touch/tree/master/SlidingPanels/SlidingPanels.Lib) (`RootView`), or show a `MvxTabBarViewController` (`AuthView`).

When my app launches,

- if I tell it to load the TabBarView (`AuthView`), it works as expected.
- if I tell it to load the SlidingPanelView (`RootView`), it *also* works as expected.

The problem occurs when I load the `AuthView` and then try to `ShowViewModel<RootView>()`... basically what happens in this scenario is that I stay at the AuthView, even though I see the `CustomPresenter.Show()` method has run appropriately.

Here's the method

```
    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var viewController = (UIViewController)Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchViewCreator>().CreateView(request);
        RootController = new UIViewController();

        // This needs to be a Tab View
        if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(AuthViewModel))
        {
            _navigationController = new EmptyNavController(viewController);
            RootController.AddChildViewController(_navigationController);
            RootController.View.AddSubview(_navigationController.View);
        }

        if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(RootViewModel))
        {
            _navigationController = new SlidingPanelsNavController(viewController);
            RootController.AddChildViewController(_navigationController);
            RootController.View.AddSubview(_navigationController.View);

            AddSlidingPanel<NavigationFragment>(PanelType.LeftPanel, 280);
        }
        base.Show(request);
    }
```

And [here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/5a7267595a45c8dd7315) of the complete class

What am I missing in trying to make this work appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if what I've done is "correct" but it's working for now. I'm still very much open to better answers.

What I've done in order to simply move on from this problem is add a call to `SetWindowRootViewController(_navigationController);` just before I call `base.Show(request)`

```
    public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {    
        _navigationController = null;

        var viewController = (UIViewController)Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchViewCreator>().CreateView(request);
        RootController = new UIViewController();

        // This needs to be a Tab View
        if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(AuthViewModel))
        {
            _navigationController = new EmptyNavController(viewController);
            RootController.AddChildViewController(_navigationController);
            RootController.View.AddSubview(_navigationController.View);
        }

        else if (request.ViewModelType == typeof (RootViewModel))
        {
            _navigationController = new SlidingPanelsNavController(viewController);
            RootController.AddChildViewController(_navigationController);
            RootController.View.AddSubview(_navigationController.View);

            AddSlidingPanel<NavigationFragment>(PanelType.LeftPanel, 280);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("They View Type you're trying to show isn't currently supported.");
        }

        // RIGHT HERE
        SetWindowRootViewController(_navigationController);

        base.Show(request);
    }
```